# Meteor isServer not called immediately

Tags: meteor

I am currently having a problem of calling the server-side code on SQL data, the client-side always get called first and I will have to wait for around 5 minutes or more for the server-side to be invoked. On a few occasions, the server-side is not called. Here are the rough code and file structure. is there a way to call the server-side without waiting for long?

statistics.html, page to call the server

```html
<template name="statistics">
    <div class="content">

        <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-lg-2">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary getdata" >Get stats</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

statistics.js, to call getData function

```js
Template.statistics.events({
    'click .getdata'(event, instance){
        alert("get data")
        Meteor.call('getSqlData', function(err, response) {
            if(err){
                console.log("err is "+err)
            }
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```

sqlData.js, function getSqlData

```js
Meteor.methods({
getSqlData: function(){
        console.log("at sqldata");
        if(Meteor.isClient){
            console.log("shouldn't be here")
        }
        if(Meteor.isServer){
            console.log("server side")
            //go to a directory and get the file names to be read
            //get the data in the files and insert into mongoDB
        }
});
```

my file structure is place in this manner 
Project
├── imports
│   ├── ui
│   │   ├── pages
│   │   │   ├── statistics.js
│   │   │   ├── statistics.html
├── lib
│   ├── collections
│   │   ├── sqlData.js

Comment: Do you mean it takes 5 minutes after you click to get a response from the server, or that the call doesn't make it to the server for 5 minutes?

Comment: What's your meteor version ?

Comment: @KellyCopley 5 minutes after i click to get a response. most of the time the call doesn't make it to the server

Comment: @GaëtanRouziès 1.9.3